# XMLHttpRequest problem

Tags: xmlhttprequest, xul, status, readystate

I am writing one Web Application using XUL. In that Iam using AJAX XMLHttpRequest Object for sending request to server. When I use GPRS connection to send the request to the server from my web application the request is not going, but readyState has changed to 4 and status=0. If the request is not going out how the readyState is Changing.

The same Code working fine in local network. If I send the request to server from the browser using GPRS it is working fine. Can any body help me out in solving this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

> the request is not going

How do you determine that?

Do you use the HTTP scheme? If so, status == 0 is an issue, ([google says](http://www.google.com/search?q=xmlhttprequest+status+0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) there are known quirks in Firefox).

status == 0 is also returned when the request is using a non-HTTP protocol. So if you're making a file:// request accidentally, it would explain all the symptoms...

[edit 2009-09-07]
Also found this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=488605
aborted XMLHttpRequests have status==0 since Firefox 3.

[edit] I'm not /quite/ sure, but I think that cross-domain requests that are not allowed also end up with status == 0.