# XULrunner adding unsafe: before links when using Angular

Tags: javascript, firefox, angularjs, xul, xulrunner

I'm trying to use a simple Angular page (no xhr except for loading the templates) and so far [it's not been easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093931/is-history-replacestate-broken-for-xul-applications-and-plugins).

Somehow there are differences in how Firefox would run script/renders html and how XUL would. These differences are undocumented as far as I know since I've been looking for the last hour or so to figure out why a link would have `unsafe:` before it. Can guess it's because the content is considered unsafe but can't find any documentation for it.

My main html page is inside a XUL browser element with it's type set to `content-primary` and it's source set to `chrome://myapp/content/index.html`

Direct links in the main page and in the first loaded template work:

```
<a href='#/students/JON'>link in the template</a>
```

I can click on it and it'll load the details template and show the data.

When I let Angular generate the links in a ng-repeat it doesn't work anymore:

```
<a href="#/students/{{student.name}}">{{student.name}}</a>
```

The href of this link is changed to: `unsafe:chrome://myapp/content/index.html#/students/JON`

The following is changed as well:

```
<a href='#/students/{{"JON"}}'>messed with by angular</a>
```

This would suggest that JS generated hrefs are considered unsafe yet the following works fine:

```
  var a=document.createElement("a");
  a.href="#/students/JON";
  a.innerHTML="dynamic added link same url";
  document.body.appendChild(a);
```

When clicking on that link the details template is loaded and details are displayed.

So my question is: How can I prevent XUL from considering the links as unsafe? They all point to local resources in `chrome://myapp/content/` and setting the link as `chrome://myapp/content/index.html#/sudents/JON` isn't working either (still unsafe).

Another one is: Is there good documentation about XUL rendering things differently and executing JS differently than Firefox? If there is a such a document then it surely contains the unsafe part and probably other things I'm going to run into.

**[update]**
Thanks to Mr Maier I've figured out that it isn't a XUL issue at all. Since before XUL was refusing location.replaceState for chrome content and then was returning status 0 instead of 200 (like in Firefox) I assumed it was XUL related as well. Should have known it was Angular because adding dom elements worked (angular wasn't aware I added them) and links that were not processed by angular worked. To add the chrome:// protocol as trusted I've done the following:

```
angular.module('student', []).
  config(['$routeProvider','$compileProvider', 
    function($routeProvider,$compileProvider) {
      $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(chrome|file):/);
```

Will remove file later as I'm using it at the moment to open the file from disk in Firefox to see if everything still works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to do with XUL per-se. This is an [AngularJS feature](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compileProvider#aHrefSanitizationWhitelist) ([use](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/5bb9ba2c54b341aa9d6a26934831f5b72f24ddac/src/ng/compile.js#L369-L382)), that does not work in `chrome:` as expected, apparently. You'll have to fix this, e.g. by white-listing the [`chrome:` protocol](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/5bb9ba2c54b341aa9d6a26934831f5b72f24ddac/src/ng/compile.js#L156).

Answer (score 2):

When using bindings in the href attribute of links, you should use **ng-href** rather than href so the bindings are evaluated. e.g.

```
<a ng-href="#/students/{{student.name}}">{{student.name}}</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="#/students/{{student.name}}">{{student.name}}</a>
```

See the angular documentation at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngHref

Comment: Also for those moving to Angular 1.2, note that $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist() has been replaced with $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist()